# Java calculating average of numbers from another file

Tags: java, file, average

```
public void computeAverage(String [] names, int [] scores, char [] grades){
    int av = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        av = (scores[i]++ / 26);
    System.out.print(av);

}
```

Hey guys,
Above is my code to read a list of test scores and compute their average.  There are 26 test scores.  I am having trouble, Please help!
Thanks

Comment: no just messing around with files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you keep writing over the `av` variable during each iteration of the loop. Also, it looks like you don't needs the `names` and `grades` arrays as parameters, as you're not using them. This should work better:

```
public void computeAverage(int [] scores)
{
    double average = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++)
    {
        average += scores[i];
    }

    average /= scores.length;

    System.out.print(average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down:

- You need to loop through your entires scores array and sum each score
  to a running total
- You need to then divide by total number of scores. As @cliff.meyers
  pointed out, that is the definition of an average
- As a side note, you are looping against name.length, but indexing
  into scores. That is bad.
- You are dividing by a hard coded constant. That is also bad.
- You don't need names or grades in the function to calculate averages.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding them all first, then dividing by the total number. That's how you calculate an average...

Comment: Yea I know but they are in a file and are all stored in the array scores[]

Answer (score 0):

You need to **add** the contributions to the running tally:

```
av += (scores[i] / 26.0);
```

Perhaps even better to divide by `names.length`, and even better to leave the division to the end. Finally, be careful with integer division, which might not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int computAverage(int[] scores)
{
    long sum = 0;
    for(int i : scores)
    sum += i;
    return sum / scores.length;
}
```